# removing a exterior wall below a floor joist of the second floor

Tags: walls, load-bearing, beam, removal

I would like to remove an exterior wall (15' long) under a floor joist (14x2) that supports a second floor and house roof edge. I was wondering if the joist itself could be used as a beam to support the new opening. Or maybe it (the floor joist) will need a reinforcement by adding a 2x12?!

Better explained in the attached images. The first is the original wall, and the second is what I think I could do.

I will really appreciate any help.

Thanks!

[image: original wall]
  [image: Possibly option to remove wall??!!]

Answer (score 3):

You’re lucky, you will not need to add a support floor joist or beam provided: 1) the floor joists run the direction you show, 2) roof joists run the same direction as the floor joists, 3) the remaining second floor wall does not have a window (as shown), 4) the remaining second floor wall has a minimum of 1/2” plywood sheathing or 1/2” OSB board sheathing.

1) There is no floor load on the wall you want to remove, if the floor joists run the direction you show. (If the first floor joist is more than 8” from the exterior, you’ll need to add a sister joist where the wall is being removed.)

2) There will be no roof load on the wall you want to remove if the roof joists run the same direction as the floor joist.

3) and 4) The remaining second floor wall is a “giant” beam that only needs to support itself and a portion of the roof wall above.

However, if any of the issues I’ve outlined above are different, then you’ll need to add a support beam...or at least double (or triple) the floor joist where the the wall is to be removed.

The existing footing at the existing post is supporting 1/4 the existing floor load. There is not much load (about 3,100 lbs. plus roof load, if any) transferred to the footing, but should be verified. About 18” x 18” should be adequate, unless your soil condition is a swamp.

Comment: Thanks for the very explained reply.  I really appreciate it.  I will take a look in more detail, of the roof and the remaining of the second floor beam (point 4) and I will update the info...   So, now I think everything is fine, but I also understand there are some missing details that should change the result.  Thansk again for your help and I hope you could take a look and review the new updated information when placed.